# How to get multiple regression models from a list of lists to a gtsummary table?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Given the following, how can I get the two models in `out` to a `gtsummary` table?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

m.1.1 <- "cyl"
m.1.2 <- paste(c(m.1.1, "disp"), collapse = " + ")

out <- map(dplyr::lst(m.1.1, m.1.2), 
           ~ lm(data = mtcars, formula = as.formula(paste0("mpg ~ ", .x))))
```

I think that I want to use `tbl_regression` and `tbl_merge`, but -- basing my code off of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294935/using-tbl-regression-for-multivariable-regression-on-nested-data-frames?noredirect=1&lq=1) -- I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you can use `tbl_regression()` and `tbl_merge()` to prepare the table. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- 
  c("cyl", "cyl + disp") %>%            # vector of covariates
  map(
    ~ paste("mpg", .x, sep = " ~ ") %>% # build character formula
      as.formula() %>%                  # convert to proper formula
      lm(data = mtcars) %>%             # build linear regression model
      tbl_regression()                  # display table with gtsummary
  ) %>%
  # merge tables into single table
  tbl_merge(
    tab_spanner = c("**Univariate**", "**Multivariable**")
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>